# Is it a good practise to have database operations in a middleware?

Tags: mysql, performance, express, redis, middleware

Assume that, With an expressjs server, on a request we have to fetch a data(possibly a keyword data) from redis database and then we have to query the mysql database with that redis data.

Is it a good practise to create a middleware for fetching the redis data and then pass that data onto the next middleware to query the mysql database. Will this approach affects the performance of API when the API gets more requests?

Comment: That said the format of your question is not a good one. You are basically asking for an opinion. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Oh, now I understood. Thanks @Joe, will follow the guidelines from now. Again Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like "premature optimization".  *Start with* a simple solution.

1. Go straight to the database for all "persisted" data.
2. If that does not run fast enough, look for ways to optimize the SQL.  (This is a common issue in this forum.  I regularly provide 10x improvements in SQL.)
3. Only if that is not sufficient, consider adding complexity to your app.
4. As a last resort, beef up your hardware.  (This can be done only once, and rarely improves performance by a factor of 2.)

Notes on your ideas:

- Putting a cache in front of a cache is usually not useful.
- Fetching from one place, then reaching into another takes extra effort, complexity, and time.